# Opencart Version 2.0.3.1, Review button on product page not working

Tags: opencart, e-commerce, opencart2.x

I wish to add a review function in my old e-commerce website. However, the "write a review" button does not seems to be working, it will not bring me to a review page; seems like a broken link. I followed the opencart [documentation](http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/catalog/review/) review  but there is just this bug.

> I am using opencart Version 2.0.3.1.

[image: review]

[image: no review displayed]
[image: console]

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? What template is your Store using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there is something wrong with **review** tab on your product page.

Due to may OpenCart experience. The best code for this "Write a review" button is:

```
<a href="" onclick="$('a[href=\'#tab-review\']').trigger('click'); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('ul.nav-tabs').offset().top},'slow'); return false;">Write a review</a>
```

It should work better, then a standard one.

If this wouldn't help - please, write a link to your website and i'll correct the answer.

---

**UPDATED**

No your *product.tpl* find `<div id="tab-review" class="tab-content">`. It should be like

```
  <?php if ($review_status) { ?>
  <div id="tab-review" class="tab-content">
    <div id="review"></div>
```

On the bottom of this file you can look for script

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#review .pagination a').live('click', function() {
    $('#review').fadeOut('slow');
        
    $('#review').load(this.href);
    
    $('#review').fadeIn('slow');
    
    return false;
});         

$('#review').load('index.php?route=product/product/review&product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>');

$('#button-review').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/write&product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'name=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'name\']').val()) + '&text=' + encodeURIComponent($('textarea[name=\'text\']').val()) + '&rating=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'rating\']:checked').val() ? $('input[name=\'rating\']:checked').val() : '') + '&captcha=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'captcha\']').val()),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.success, .warning').remove();
            $('#button-review').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#review-title').after('<div class="attention"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /> <?php echo $text_wait; ?></div>');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-review').attr('disabled', false);
            $('.attention').remove();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['error']) {
                $('#review-title').after('<div class="warning">' + data['error'] + '</div>');
            }
            
            if (data['success']) {
                $('#review-title').after('<div class="success">' + data['success'] + '</div>');
                                
                $('input[name=\'name\']').val('');
                $('textarea[name=\'text\']').val('');
                $('input[name=\'rating\']:checked').attr('checked', '');
                $('input[name=\'captcha\']').val('');
            }
        }
    });
});
//--></script>
```

If there is no such script - add it.

Then, in the same folder as *product.tpl* find *review.tpl* with code

```
<?php if ($reviews) { ?>
<?php foreach ($reviews as $review) { ?>
<div class="review-list">
  <div class="author"><b><?php echo $review['author']; ?></b> <?php echo $text_on; ?> <?php echo $review['date_added']; ?></div>
  <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars-<?php echo $review['rating'] . '.png'; ?>" alt="<?php echo $review['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
  <div class="text"><?php echo $review['text']; ?></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="pagination"><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="content"><?php echo $text_no_reviews; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

If there is no such file - add id.

If all the conditions are OK, but it still not working - here a screenshot of your console errors.

---

**UPDATED 2**

check your *config.php* in foot folder ans set both `HTTP_SERVER` and `HTTPS_SERVER` to the same protocol you are using, like

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://yoursite.com/');
// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://yoursite.com/');
```

Make sure that you don't have any http->https redirects in your `.htaccess`.

Comment: Please, tell if this helped you.

Comment: I do not know where the code is so i might just keep it on hold first as i have a more important problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62218124/how-do-i-add-image-and-dropdown-for-opencart-v2-product-page can you help me here?  I did not use opencart before and I only want to make some changes here so really appreciate if you can help Thanks in advance :D

Comment: please check the question i have screenshot the problem thanks

Comment: Any live site link?

Comment: do you know what could be the problem? why does the review get displayed out?

Comment: the codes you ask me to add are similar to what i have now, i have screenshot the console pls take a look. Thanks

Comment: There is another problem which is after i rate 1-5 the "write a review" will become the price of the product? do you know why is it like this?

Comment: do you know how can i share my existing code here? so that it will be easier for u to take a look?

Comment: can you check your config.php and make sure there is `http://` or `https://` everywhere in configs? Not both, set the same please

Comment: The check the title error - need to see whole .tpl and .php controller. If you put this website to the internet - it will be much easier.

Comment: okay something weird just happened by default http and https is define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://' . URL); so i change it to  define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://localhost/shop' . URL); everything is messed up e.g i could not see all the images so i change it back to define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://' . URL); and the review thing worked? Do you know what exactly happen here?

Comment: could you edit the ans so i can accept? by the way the "write a review" circle in blue in img will change to "SGD799.00" everytime i rate the product. is this some kind of bug in opencart?

Comment: Updated the answer. About "write a review" changing. I think it's bug of your template. Need to see whole code to solve it. With the live site it will be perfectly easy.

Comment: okay i will try to solve the bug thanks for your help!